# Полный стек вызова функций PHP

Tags: php, отладка

Подскажите инструмент для анализа полного последовательного вызова функций и методов с указанием передаваемых аргументов при выполнении PHP кода.

Например есть стандартный Frontend контроллер в Symfony.

```
<?php
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';
if (PHP_VERSION_ID < 70000) {
    include_once __DIR__.'/../var/bootstrap.php.cache';
}
$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', false);
if (PHP_VERSION_ID < 70000) {
    $kernel->loadClassCache();
}
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
$response = $kernel->handle($request);
$response->send();
$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

И я хочу получить полный стек вызова при его исполнении, добавив конец что-то наподобие этого

```
....
$response->send();
$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
**DEBUG FUNCTION**
```

Я пробовал использовать Xdebug с профилированием, но при просмотре cachegrind он не показывает передаваемые аргументы, к тому же он представляет информацию в виде дерева, а нужна именно последовательность, на подобие того что выводит debug_print_backtrace:

```
#0 c(Cleveland) called at [C:\webfolder\test.php:6]
#1 b(Glenn) called at [C:\webfolder\test.php:3]
#2 a(Peter) called at [C:\webfolder\test.php:11]
```

но при вызове debug_print_backtrace в Front контроллере, он не покажет Trace других функций.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.debug-backtrace.php

Comment: показывает, выберете во Frames нужный метод и нажмите на него, потом перейдите  в код этого метода и нажмите на любой строчке. В разделе Variables у вас будут вашы параметры

Comment: @MykolaVeriga
Выбрал метод. Показывает только его код, а variables не вижу

[https://yadi.sk/i/MsIZVbDA3Usy5G](https://yadi.sk/i/MsIZVbDA3Usy5G)

Comment: добавил картинку внизу

Comment: @MykolaVeriga
Но если в Shtorm поставить точку останова в верхнем слое кода (например в контроллере), то он не будет показывать Trace вызова других функций
[https://d.radikal.ru/d40/1804/1c/68fc9762d2c4.png](https://d.radikal.ru/d40/1804/1c/68fc9762d2c4.png)

Comment: он показывает путь который прошел интерпритатор к указаной точке останова. Странно что вы хотите от него, как он может показать то где еще не был? Хотите в глубине увидеть там и ставьте точку останова

Answer (score 0):

здесь видно где смотреть параметры. Если у вас нет такого раздела, посмотрите инструкцию настройки
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]